# loading contacts from email

Tags: php, api, contacts

After finishing your signup process in facebook, a page will load asking you if you want to load contacts from your email account and their profile images (be it gmail, yahoo, ...etc).

My question is : is there any API that can do this for me?

Notice : I know this question was asked before but the last time it've been asked was on 2008, so I expect that many other choices appeared since that year.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Every mail / contacts provider will have its own API I reckon... That's why you usually are only offered to check the top-N mail-providers, and not _any_ mail provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [OpenInviter](http://openinviter.com/) or [GetmyContacts](http://getmycontacts.com/).

Comment: thanks , I will try them both +1

Answer (score 1):

See [Contact Grabber](http://sourceforge.net/projects/contactgrabber/)

Comment: thank you so much.. It's really helpfull, actually I have many solutions now,have only to choose one :) +1